# Make the IF function provide a numerical answer

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use the IF function to prevent negative and zero values in my data. This the code that I use

```
=IF(C4<=0;"0.01";"Sheet1!$B$5*(Sheet1!$B$6-C4)*(Sheet1!$B14)+(C4)^0.5*(Sheet1!$B$7)*(Sheet1!E14)*(Sheet1!$B14^0.5)+C4")
```

What I would like is that if the value in cell C4 is equal or below zero, it should provide the number 0.01. However if this is not true I would like excel to calculate the value from the equation that I have stated in the "if false" argument. When I use the code written above, the IF function only returns my code and not the actual calculation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take out the double quotes ("):

```
=IF(C4<=0; 0.01 ; Sheet1!$B$5*(Sheet1!$B$6-C4)*(Sheet1!$B14)+(C4)^0.5*(Sheet1!$B$7)*(Sheet1!E14)*(Sheet1!$B14^0.5)+C4 )
```

double quotes make everything in between be processed as text, and not as numbers or formulas

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(C4<=0,0.01,Sheet1!$B$5*(Sheet1!$B$6-C4)*(Sheet1!$B14)+(C4)^0.5*(Sheet1!$B$7)*(Sheet1!E14)*(Sheet1!$B14^0.5)+C4)`

You have semicolons and quotes in your formula which renders it unworkable

Comment: Semicolon isnt the problem, I have those in my Dutch version of office as well. In the US version indeed the separators are comma. However in parts of the world where the comma is the decimal separator function arguments are devided by semicolon mostly...

Comment: @K_B thanks for the update, my .uk version threw a fit at the semicolons - I will try to remember the version differences in future!